# How to insert task list and dependencies among them in a .csv file to database?

Tags: php, excel, csv

I have an excel file in .csv format with task list.
I have an table for task_dependency where taskid and dependency id will be stored.
I want to add an additional column in my .csv file for dependency tasks with ne tasks list so that when i upload the file then tasks and their corresponding dependencies should be inserted to those tables.

Comment: how an excel file end-up as csv? that's surprise me

Comment: right sir, i have an excel file with .csv extension

Comment: NO, excel is excel, CSV is CSV. You can use microsoft excel to open a CSV file, and the CSV file will parse nicely by microsoft excel.

Comment: can u solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I could think of:

First duplicate lines for each dependency like this:

```
task_id;dependency_id;title
1;2;Test1
1;3;Test1
2;;Test2
3;2;Test3
```

Second would be to split dependencies by a character like a colon:

```
task_id;dependencies;title
1;2,3;Test1
2;;Test2
3;2;Test3
```

Now you would need to write an importer script for the method you use and insert the values and it's dependencies... This logic may or may not be a little complicated - For example with foreign key constraints enabled you need to first create the tasks without dependencies and then the tasks not created yet but required by other tasks and so on until you have created all task dependencies... Or you could first write all your tasks to a tasks table and then write the dependencies (I think this would be much easier done.)

Comment: thanks you so much shindo but i dont know the task id and dependency id,i just inserting all task name and id is autogenerated.i  want to insert dependency among those tasks at the same time from same .csv file.

Comment: You need a unique identifier for each task (e.x. the name or an imaginary id or such) - Use this for the id fields ;)